# How to use only the column as the parameter in a 1 row to 1 row return pl/sql function in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, function, plsql

I have written this function`fexemplo` called like this:

```
select fexemplo(id) from texemplo;
```

**id** is the primary key of the table texemplo.

texemplo is as follows:

```
Name                       Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 ID                    NOT NULL NUMBER(10)
 TVALUE                         NUMBER(10)
```

The function adds 10 to the value in `tvalue` attribute.

So if we have:

```
select * from texemplo;


    ID     TVALUE
---------- ----------
     1     20
     3     59
```

Then:

```
select fexemplo(id) from texemplo;
```

Is going to return:

```
FEXEMPLO(ID)
------------
      30
      69
```

The function code I am using is:

```
create or replace function fexemplo (pid IN NUMBER)
RETURN NUMBER
IS
    vteste NUMBER(10);
BEGIN
    SELECT tvalue
    INTO vteste
    FROM texemplo
    WHERE id=pid;
    vteste := vteste+10;
    RETURN vteste;
END fexemplo;
/
```

It works fine - it returns one result for each row as expected. However I want this function to be generic. So, I want it to work with other table like this one:

```
Name                       Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 USERID                         VARCHAR2(50)
 AGE                            NUMBER(10)
 PHOTO                          BLOB
 NOFFRIENDS                     NUMBER(10)
```

I want to add 10 to the NOFFRIENDS column.
I should be able to execute **the same** function on this other table.
Therefore **I cannot** use the id as parameter. The function code has to be totaly different.

The parameter I want to use is the NUMBER, so I could execute it on both the tables:

```
 select fexemplo(tvalue) from texemplo;
```

OR

```
select fexemplo(noffriends) from utable;
```

The return is still 1 row to 1 row.

The `tvalue` and `noffriends` column might have repeated values.

The function code is probably tottaly different.

How could I make it?

**Another example is**: how could I make an ABS function by myself?

How could I make the ABS function on PL/SQL?

The function is explained here:

[ABS function](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/abs.php)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why would you want to write your own ABS() function? If it is for the intellectual challenge asking us to write it for you rather spoild things.

Comment: It is an example... just an example... 
I want to do another thing... that is to illustrate my issue... just it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling your function like this ...

```
select fexemplo(id) from texemplo;
```

... so you can avoid the need to query a table itself. As your question actually says, all you need to do is change the value passed as the input parameter to the column being modified:

```
  select fexemplo(tvalue) from texemplo;
```

Not only is this version simpler and more obvious it is also completely generic;

```
create or replace function fexemplo (pid IN NUMBER)
RETURN NUMBER
is
begin
    return pid + 10;
end;
```

Comment: Is that really the question that was asked? I completely misunderstood it !!

Comment: That is it... very simple...
Thanks for your attention.